# Webpack require method returns unexpected object

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have recently upgraded my webpack from verion 1.12.9 to 1.12.13 and babel from 5 to 6, part of my code breaks after the upgrade:

```
const DevTools = require('../components/DevTools.js')
DevTools.instrument()
```

I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: DevTools.instrument is not a function
```

Then I added `console.log(DevTools)` before calling `instrument()`, and this is the output in Chrome's console:

```
> Object {__esModule: true}
  > __esModule: true
  > default: DevTools(props, context)
  > __proto__: Object
```

To fix this issue, I used `import` instead of `require`:

```
import DevTools from '../components/DevTools.js'
```

Print `console.log(DevTools)` again would give this:

```
DevTools(props, context) {
      _classCallCheck(this, DevTools);
      var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _Component.call(this, props, context));
      if (!props.store && !…
```

This is exactly what I want to import and works fine now.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Is this error due to the upgrade of webpack or babel?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of always importing DevTools, you could also require them conditionally with the addition of `default`

```
const DevTools = require('../components/DevTools.js').default;
```